# Generate English alphabets on user choice with while condition in C-language

Tags: c

Since, i am kinda very new to C-language I have to build a program which work user-friendly. Like user will give instructions of i need A to Z alphabets and after execute he will get result by using while condition. Is that possible ?.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
    char c;
    for(c='A'; c<='Z'; ++c)
       printf("%c ",c);
    return 0;
}
```

Like that if I can write it using hard coded values, What if I have to give input From which Alphabet to Alphabet you want result and it give result till user want using while loop.

Comment: Can you please include in the question, some sample inputs and required outputs, and the code showing what you have tried?

Comment: You can use `getchar` to input each of the start and end characters.

Comment: Can you explain it in code, I am not much friendly with C-language yet, Thanks

Comment: StackOverflow is meant for specific questions. You can easily find tons of online examples on how to read input from the console ...

Comment: Have a go, this is not a code writing service! Step 1: `int first = getchar();`.

Comment: Got it, any reference of like that program example you guys have. i know stackOverflow is not for code service, but i am really new with C-language so it could be very beneficial for me to have the idea for how to make work like that program in code, Anyways I hope that reference link will help alot. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char c;
    char b;

    printf("Enter the first letter\n");
    c=getchar();
    getchar();
    printf("Enter the last letter\n");
    b=getchar();
    getchar();

    for ( ;c<=b; ++c)
    {
        printf("%c", c);
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the return type for `getchar`? Why is that?

Comment: Yes, this is what i need look like. What if i also can give user choice till which alphabet User can get result. It will be perfect program as i wanted. Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot. Thumbs up